# \nocorr inside argument of a command followed by \textup

Tags: italic, italic-correction

In the following `\lex` command I somehow need `\textup` to protect the argument from italicizing in some contexts.

Could someone explain why `\textup` in the `\lexb` variant forces italic correction in spite of `\nocorr`?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\NewDocumentCommand{\lexa}{mm}{\textit{#1\nocorr}\textsubscript{\textup{\textsc{#2}}}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\lexb}{mm}{\textit{#1\nocorr}\textup{\textsubscript{\textsc{#2}}}}

\begin{document}
    
    
    \lexa{of}{prep}
    
    \lexb{of}{prep}
    
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `\nocorr` in the second `\textup` or use `\upshape`.

Comment: Any idea why it does that?

Comment: `\textup` also inserts italic correction. Compare `f\textup{H}` with `fH`.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `Stephen` pointed out, `\textup` also adds italic correction.

So we have to add `\nocorr` inside the argument of `\textup` as well.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\lexb}{mm}{\textit{#1\nocorr}\textup{\nocorr\textsubscript{\textsc{#2}}}}
```

So here is a **MWE**:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\NewDocumentCommand{\lexb}{mm}{\textit{#1\nocorr}\textup{\nocorr\textsubscript{\textsc{#2}}}}

\begin{document}
    
    \lexb{of}{prep}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As a remark, please notice that `\nocorr` must be added before anything else inside the argument of `\textup`; most probably because the command for italic correction is located at the beginning of the definition of `\textup` (while it is at the end of `\textit`).

```
\textit{f\textup{\nocorr H}} % This removes italic correction.

\textit{f\textup{H\nocorr}} % This does NOT remove italic correction.
```

[image]